# Unable to return data object from $http jsonp $q.defer

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, angular-promise

when i console.log(getUserData()) i get Promise {$$state: Object} but how can i retrieve actual value from this returned $$state object so the output be [someArray] or {someObject}..

```
getUserData = function(){
var defer = $q.defer();
$http.jsonp('http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.js?area='+localData.area_name+'&api_key=xxx&jsonp=someCallback')
 someCallback = function(userData){
     //console.log(userData);
       defer.resolve(userData)
    }
    return defer.promise;
 };
console.log(getUserData())
```

Answer (score 1):

That function returns promise. So you'll need to handle it properly.
You expect async code to behave syncronously

```
getUserData = function(){
var defer = $q.defer();
$http.jsonp('http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.js?area='+localData.area_name+'&api_key=xxx&jsonp=someCallback')
 someCallback = function(userData){
     //console.log(userData);
       defer.resolve(userData)
    }
    return defer.promise;
 };

getUserData().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

More about angular deffered and promises: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: so we endup having data inside  .then again, is there way to get this returned data out of callback inside .then so it can be used in different function.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this console.log(userData.data);
```

OR

```
$http.get('http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.js?area='+localData.area_name+'&api_key=xxx&jsonp=someCallback';

 then yourService.getUserData().success(function('success',data){
   data
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers){status, headers});
```

Comment: console.log(getUserData.data) will return undefined.
can't use $http.get as it the api doesn's allow cross domain so only way is jsonp
using success won't allow me to use data outside callback as it is async ...hence i used $q.defer

Comment: ow ok
For developpment I use chrome and in the command invite I start it with this command google-chrome --disable-web-security for cross-domain